# Number of open and closed rook's tours

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, chessboard, knight-tours

Knight's tour is very well known problem, but what about rook's tour? On $n\times1$ chessboard there are obviously $n!$ open and $(n-1)!$ closed tours.

Is there a way to easily compute number of open and closed rook's tours on $n\times m$ (or just for some small $m$) chessboard? Question doesn't look trivial, so I don't know what can be added to make it more informative. I will appreciate any references.

Comment: See [A096121](http://oeis.org/A096121) for $n\times2$ and [A096970](http://oeis.org/A096970) for $n\times n$.

Comment: Forgot to mention, those references are for **open** tours. I didn't see anything on closed tours.

Comment: @bof, thank you very much!

Comment: @bof, can you please also (if you have time) look for a proof of $n\times2$?

Comment: Now the last thing is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4054081).